# EditText on InputKeyboard launch Creating IME in android

Tags: android, android-input-method

I am creating my own IME for device. What I need to add is a TextBox above keyboardView as shown in below image. Although I am able to display it as shown in below image but I am unable to write text into it.

[image]

I am extending keyboard view and below is the layout structure

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:background="@color/background" > 

   <TextView android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/txtTest" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Test" ></TextView>
       <EditText android:inputType="text" android:id="@+id/edtTest" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>

<com.keyboard.CustomKeyboardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/keyboard"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:keyTextSize="15sp"
       />
  </LinearLayout>
```

public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {

```
static final int KEYCODE_OPTIONS = -100;

private TextView mResultText;
public CustomKeyboardView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    }

public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected boolean onLongPress(Key key) {
    if (key.codes[0] == Keyboard.KEYCODE_CANCEL) {
        getOnKeyboardActionListener().onKey(KEYCODE_OPTIONS, null);
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onLongPress(key);
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Nil

Comment: Could you provide at least your layout? Are you extending KeyboardView?

Comment: @Laurent updated with code do I need to add anything else to the layout?

Comment: I think this is your Activity layout, not your CustomKeyboardView layout. Could you provide the CustomKeyboardView layout (or onCreate()) ?

Comment: In which textbox do you want to enter text? The EditText or the TextView? Is this layout your application's or is this the layout of your inputmethodservice?

Comment: @Laurent the layout above I have added is the input.xml and in OnCreateInputView we are loading this layout. And there is no code added to CustomKeyboardView still edited to just to clarify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture your softkeyboard events and transmit them to your own widgets by implementing [`KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.html).

In your `Inputmethodservice.onKey()` Method, you should try to transmit the event to your InputView subviews like this:

```
public class mySoftKeyboard 
    extends InputMethodService 
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

// Implementation of KeyboardViewListener inside your InputMethodService
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        //assuming your inputview is in private variable mInputView 
        //and contains public members txtTst and edtTst views 
        //(arrange for this in your InputView.onCreate)
        //Here, we just transmit the onKey code to View.onKeyDown/Up and let views draw themselves
        sendKey( mInputView.txtTst , primaryCode ); // send this to your TextView
        sendKey( mInputView.edtTst , primaryCode ); // also send to your EditText
    }

/**
 * Helper to send a character to the editor as raw key events.
 */
private void sendKey(View v, int keyCode) {
          v.onKeyDown(keyCode,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyCode));
          v.onKeyUp  (keyCode,new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyCode));
}
    //other interface function, no need to implement
public void onText(CharSequence text){}
public void swipeRight() {}
public void swipeLeft() {}
public void swipeDown() {}
public void swipeUp() {}
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {}
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {}
}
```

---

**Edit**

To answer your comment about the difference between glyph and keycode, here's a code snippet that can help you:

```
//This snippet tries to translate the glyph 'primaryCode' into key events

//retrieve the keycharacter map from a keyEvent (build yourself a default event if needed)
KeyCharacterMap myMap=KeyCharacterMap.load(event.getDeviceId()); 

//event list to reproduce glyph
KeyEvent evs[]=null;

//put the primariCode into an array
char chars[]=new char[1];
chars[0]=primaryCode;

// retrieve the key events that could have produced this glyph
evs=myMap.getEvents(chars);

if (evs != null){
    // we can reproduce this glyph with this key event array
    for (int i=0; i< evs.length;i++) mySendKeyMethodHelper(evs[i]);
}
else { /* could not find a way to reproduce this glyph */ }
```

Comment: Hi Laurent thanks for your reply,I tried overriding the onKey method but its still not working. I am loading the Custom Layout as given above along with CustomKeyboardView. So suppose we click on the 'To' field of Messaging application, we see that keyboard getting launched with our layout (i.e with EditText shown above), but no matter what we do all the text that we enter using the Keyboard (which is my custom IME) goes to the'To' field of Messaging application and not to EditText that is currently displayed. It seems the IME is binded with 'To' field and we are not able to change it.

Comment: It *is* bounded to the field which has focus (the To field in your case). Per design. You still can get key events in onKey an defer them to your own textviews.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you must implement OnKeyboardActionListener to get a chance to capture keys. See the updated code.

Comment: Thank you Laurent you are a life saver... finally did it with your suggestions. The only thing is it is not showing the exact characters. But will manage it, must do something with primarycode or keycodes, maybe related with the unicode or like that...

Comment: @nilMoBile I just added a snippet I coded in my softkeyboard to handle this kind of issues. The trick is to get a KeyCharacterMap and use it to translate unicode characters into keyEvents list. (To send characters to a textview one needs to get an InputConnection which I found only available when the editext has focus)

Comment: I have updated the code snippet. I am using regarding the glyph code, as I have to send the key codes to the field which is not associated with the current input connection, so it seems I have to use sendKey method.
If I do some modifications on primaryCode such as subtracting (primaryCode-68) then it will print the correct Alphabets.

Comment: Sorry I was misleading: the snippet I added yesterday do *not* need InputConnection. All it does is to produce an array of keyEvents that can be sent to your views to reproduce the character.